# Ubuntu xampp cant run python script

Tags: php, python, xampp, scikit-learn, lamp

for some reasons i have to move my web application on my local machine. i need to extract some information from a python script.
I've followed al lot of guides, and answers here on stackoverflow, but i have a strange problem.
I got a simple web app that from jquery with an ajax call to a php file, retrieve some information from a python script, then the php file elaborate them and send back to javascript.
My problem is with the PHP file:

```
<?php
$test = 'just a string to elaborate';
$result = system("cd ~/Scrivania/test && python script3.py ". escapeshellarg($test));
var_dump($result);
?>
```

and the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, f1_score
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
string = sys.argv[1]
sets = load_files('scikit') #carico il set




count_vect = CountVectorizer() #bigrammi count_vect = CountVectorizer() per bags of words
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(sets.data)     #applico al set



tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit(X_train_counts)
X_train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(X_train_counts)


tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)



clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, sets.target)
docs_new = [string]
X_new_counts = count_vect.transform(docs_new)
X_new_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(X_new_counts)
predicted = clf.predict(X_new_tfidf)
for doc, category in zip(docs_new, predicted):
     #print('%r => %s' % (doc, sets.target_names[category]))
     #print(sets.target_names)
     print(clf.predict_proba(X_new_tfidf))
```

This command would not be executed, and in the error log i got:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "script3.py", line 5, in
>   
>       from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer importError: No module named sklearn.feature_exctraction.text

obviously scikit-learn and all it's components are installed, and it works great, if i run from shell the same command it works and gave me correct output.
If i try to run a different script instead the current one, something like :

```
import sys 
import os
print('hello')
```

I got the output.
I cant really figure out what is the problem and why python called from php cant load scikit.
I know that call python scripts from php is not a good idea but is not  a definitive solution (i just need a version of my app that works offline).
python version : 2.7;
I already tried to move inside cgi-bin folder.
Any help would be really appreciated.
Nico

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck for days with the same issue, here's what i found out :

There a difference between your local libraries and the one used by xamp/Mamp , that's why the basic python script run and not the one with imports.

What do you have to do is to copy your local lib (sklearn ..etc) and paste it in the xamp lib folder, worked for me like a charm.

~ Cheers